# Flash over flow

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

I am using STM32CubeIDE with STM32G030F6Px Controller which have 64kB of Flash memory. Currently I am using 36.5kB of flash but when in add a few line of code in a function (Note CurrTemp is a global variable of uint8_t)
i.e.

```c
 int16_t sensorValue, temperatureC, temperatureK;
 int32_t voltageOut;
 sensorValue = 0; voltageOut = 0; temperatureC = 0; temperatureK = 0;

 sensorValue = (int16_t)ADCRead();
 sensorValue = (int16_t)(4095.0 - sensorValue);
 voltageOut = (int32_t)((sensorValue * 3250.0) / 4095.0);

 temperatureK = (int16_t)(voltageOut / 10.0);
 temperatureC = (int16_t)(temperatureK - 273);
 CurrTemp = (uint8_t)temperatureC;
```

I get Errors

```
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.7.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: fan_retest.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `FLASH'
c:\st\stm32cubeide_1.7.0\stm32cubeide\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127\tools\arm-none-eabi\bin\ld.exe: region `FLASH' overflowed by 2372 bytes
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:64: fan_retest.elf] Error 1
"make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

What's the issue I don't understand.

Comment: Post your linker script. Anyway, not clear what you expect as an answer. So your program is not fitting your memory. Optimize it. Or pick another MCU with enough memory.

Comment: 32G030F6 has 32K flash.  https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32g030f6.html

Comment: Hello Stark, In the datasheet link Provided by you it says 64kb

Comment: Why do you actually use floating point constants, if most of your calculations look like just integer based calculations? What's the benefit here to use floating point calculation? Due to your casts, you truncate the results to an integer anyway after each single calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the problem is caused by using floating point calculations which pull in the math library and the all the associated exception handling code from the standard library.

To find out if this is the case you need to look in the map file output by the linker.

It is possible to stub out the error handling code and just get the floating point libraries, and maybe that will fit in a 32kB or 64kB microcontroller, but really this is not the normal way to do something like this.  The normal way to do something like this on a small microcontroller is to use fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

As **Tom V** already pointed out, the reason is probably the floating point libraries that get included in the build.

But there is a way that may reduce the memory footprint: Use `float` instead of `double`. For example, by default `3250.0` is a `double`. But if you write `3250.0f` instead, you make it `float`, which makes calculations faster and take less flash space. Remember to append **f** suffix to **all** floating point literals you use.

Still, it's better to avoid floating point calculations on targets that lack hardware floating point support.

Comment: suffix **f** helps me , but have another question regarding **stm32cubeide**, how can i make a single bit variable , because right now i have many variable which stores only **true or false** but i dont know how to declare a variable bool type in stm32cube ide so i have to declare it char type

Comment: @yashchoudhary , being unrelated to the original question, this one deserves to be a separate question.

Comment: #include <stdbool.h>

bool foo = true;
bool bar = false;

Comment: Even though, you _could_ use stdbool, in >C99  the minimum addressable unit in C is a byte. It's implementation defined, *if* they can map it to a single bit. But you could try using bitfields, which again might need more code on load/store when accessing a bit, and in the end not much different to use an uint8/16/32 with bitwise operations.

Comment: Thanks all for the help , both issues are resolved. Will add second question separately.